# how to call model in laravel from controller

Tags: laravel

How to call a model in laravel.

My code is:

```
use Jacopo\Authentication\Models\Guide;

class SampleController extends BaseController 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $model='Guide';

        $guide=$model::where('guide_link','=',"guide")->get();

        print_r($guide);
    }
}
```

This will produce Class 'Guide' not found error.

Comment: Despite not formatting your code to make it readable, you have no methods in your controller.

Comment: You obviously use namespaces, but you arent in a namespace on ur own? Why are there no methods in your controller? Learn the basics of OOP and Laravel and get back.

Answer (score 1):

If you added your class you should run in terminal

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to update your class map. Otherwise autoloader may not "see" your class and you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the namespace to your string:

```
class SampleController extends BaseController 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $model='Jacopo\Authentication\Models\Guide';

        $guide=$model::where('guide_link','=',"guide")->get();

        print_r($guide);
    }
}
```

You could also resolve it from the IoC container, but you need to register it first:

```
App::bind('Guide', 'Jacopo\Authentication\Models\Guide');
```

And then you should be able to:

```
$model = App::make('Guide');

$guide = $model::where('guide_link','=',"guide")->get();
```

But this is not a very good option

Comment: `use Jacopo\Authentication\Models\Guide;` should make that unnecessary.